# How to do random matching within a certain propensity score range using MatchIt package in R

Tags: r, matching

I have a large dataset containing about 20,000 individuals. Among them, there are about 200 people classified as disease group and the remaining 19,800 classified as normal controls.
I want to do 1:1 age and gender matching between the disease group and control group.
However, it is obvious that control group far outnumber the disease group, and exact matching by nearest neighbor method only matches the same small number of controls out of the 19,800 people each time. So I am worried that the result may not be robust enough for further analysing.
Is there any way to randomly select matched controls within a certain range, i.e. of the same gender but can be 1 year younger or older than the matched disease group, so that I can repeat the analysis between my disease group and a different, but still matched control group for several times?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing why discarding most of your data makes sense.  What implied to you that imbalance is a bad thing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused on what you want. If you want more control units to be retained in the match, then just use a matching method that retains more control units, such as k:1 matching, variable-ratio matching, full matching, or template matching. How to perform all of these in `MatchIt` is explained in the Matching Methods [vignette](https://kosukeimai.github.io/MatchIt/articles/matching-methods.html). Know, though, that no matter how many control units are retained, the precision of your effect estimate will largely be driven by the size of the smaller group, which in this case is quite small (200). Regardless of the number of control units retained, exact matching is the best matching method because it ensures all confounding due to the observed variables is removed completely, whereas approximate matching methods allow some imbalance to remain. If you think you can achieve great sample size gains by relaxing the exact matching constraint a little bit, then use a caliper (also explained in the vignette).

It sounds like you also suggested creating two separate matched control groups to improve the robustness of your estimate. Performing the same analysis in both control groups does not buy you any more than just performing the same analysis in the combined control group, so you should just do that instead. There can be some benefit to trying several models using one control group (e.g., to perform cross-validation for an outcome model) and then applying a final model to the other control group to estimate the effect. In your case, I would recommend just performing a standard analysis using a single (large) matched control group.

Comment: Thank you very much!